# BSD sed vs GNU - is it capable of nested matches?

Tags: sed, osx, bsd, compatibility

This works perfectly well on any Linux :

```
$ echo foo bar | sed -n '/foo/{/bar/{;p;}}'
foo bar
```

But fails on OSXs ancient BSD variant :

```
❯  echo foo bar | sed -n  '/foo/{/bar/{;p;}}' 
sed: 1: "/foo/{/bar/{;p;}}": extra characters at the end of } command
```

Am I missing some magical incantation? 
Is there a way to write this in a portable manner ?

I'd hate to have to revert to a pipeline of `grep | grep | grep` commands.

Update : low rep here so can't upvote but thanks all repliers for your well considered advice.

Comment: If you want the lines where all the keywords appear, you could also invert the condition to make it more linear: `sed '/foo/!d; /bar/!d'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `sed` editing command should be terminated by `;` or a literal newline.  GNU `sed` is very forgiving about this.

Your script:

```
/foo/{/bar/{;p;}}
```

Expanded:

```
/foo/{
    /bar/{
        p
    }
}
```

This would work as a `sed` script fed to `sed` through `-f`.

If we make sure to replace newlines with `;` (only needed at the end of commands and `{...}` groups of commands) so that we can use it on the command line, we get

```
/foo/{/bar/{p;};}
```

This works with OpenBSD `sed` (the original did not, due to that second `;` missing).

In this particular case, this may be further simplified to

```
/foo/{/bar/p;}
```

Answer (score 2):

This appears to work on BSD `sed`:

```
$ echo -e "foo bar\nfoo\nbar" | sed -n '/foo/{/bar/p;}'
foo bar
```

As does two layers of nesting:

```
$ echo -e "foo bar\nfoo\nbar" | sed -n '/foo/{/bar/{p;};}'
foo bar
```